# Building array recursively in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to create a menuTree from fetched arrays in React. My problem is that I don't know how to build my array recursively:

Lets say I do a fetch of a mainUrl and get the array:

```
[
 {"id":"EU","type":"l","text":"Europe"},
 {"id":"AS","type":"l","text":"Asia"}
]
```

Since type is "l" i need to do another fetch: mainUrl/EU

Now i get:

```
[
 {"id":"SP","type":"l","text":"Spain"},
 {"id":"FR","type":"l","text":"France"}
]
```

Again both types are "l" so I do another fetch: mainUrl/EU/SP

Now i get:

```
[
 {"id":"MA","type":"t","text":"Madrid"}
]
```

Since type is now "t" i stop and start again with France and then Asia.

Keeping in mind that i don't know the dept of they children in the array

The my array should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "EU",
        "type": "l",
        "text": "Europe",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "SP",
                "type": "l",
                "text": "Spain",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "id": "MA",
                        "type": "t",
                        "text": "Madrid"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "FR",
                "type": "l",
                "text": "France",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "PA",
                        "type": "t",
                        "text": "Paris"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "AS",
        "type": "l",
        "text": "Asia",
        "children":[...]
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Hi, Yes, many things, my main problem is that i don't know how to push a child array inside a child object recursively. Then I also nested foreach loops that I got working, but I am trying to figure out how to do it recursively so that the dept of children dose'nt matter.

Comment: I know how to print the menuTree array out recursively, Just not how to build the array itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const mainUrl = "yourMainUrl"; 

const fetchDataTree = async url => {

  // I assume you will handle the fetch with your own method
  let countryArr = await yourFetchFunction(url);

  for (let key in countryArr) {
   if (countryArr[key].type === "l") {
     countryArr[key].children = await fetchDataTree(url + "/" + countryArr[key].id)
   }
 }

 return countryArr
}

const yourDataTree = await fetchDataTree(mainUrl);
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work? What about when the URL needs to be `mainUrl/EU/SP`?

Comment: well, i changed "mainUrl + / + id" by "url + / + id", it will work then

Comment: Thank you so much Maxime Girou! It with worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
const results = fetch("");
        function getChildren(name){
            const fetchData = fetch(name);
            fetchData.forEach(item => {
                if (item.type === "l") {
                    item.children = getChildren(item.id);
                }
            });
            return fetchData;
        }

        results.forEach(item => {
            if (item.type === "l") {
                item.children = getChildren(item.id);
            }
        });
```

and fetch is like this:

```
function fetch(u) {
    switch (u){
        case "":
            return [
                {
                    id: "EU",
                    type: "l",
                    text: "Europe"
                },
                {
                    id: "AS",
                    type: "l",
                    text: "Asia"
                }
            ]
        case "EU":
            return [
                {
                    id:"SP",
                    type:"l",
                    text:"Spain"
                },
                {
                    id:"FR",
                    type:"l",
                    text:"France"
                }
            ];
        case "SP":
            return [
                {
                    id:"MA",
                    type:"t",
                    text:"Madrid"
                }
            ];
        default:
            return [];
    }
};
```